# Find node above and under

Tags: luatex, lua

Using a `post_linebreak_filter` callback, is it possible to access the nodes positioned above and under a given node?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You have to do a lot of calculation, though. To find the position of a node use `node.dimensions()` from the head to the node (see the examples in the reference manual, beware of `glue_set`, `glue_sign` and `glue_order` in the `hlist` node) and do the same with the lines above and below. With this you could implement a river detection algorithm :).

Comment: Thanks. I'd appreciate if you stopped reading my mind though (about implementing a river detection algorithm ;))

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the `glue_set`, `glue_sign` and `glue_order` please? Also, once I have the dimensions, how do I find the nodes positioned at the same distance on other lines?

Comment: @Raphink the hlist node has `glue_set`, `glue_sign` and `glue_order` entries. You need to provide these values to the call to `node.dimensions()` (an example is provided in the reference manual). Now you have the distance of the glue and the width (= the distance of the node after the glue minus the distance of the node before the glue). Just do the same call on the previous line, but use the three values of that hlist node, of course. Just walk through the list at `prev_line.head` and either call `node.dimension()` on every interesting node or add the width yourself. Does this help?

Comment: @Raphink the three entries are important to calculate the width of the glue nodes. That's it.

Comment: Alright, I will see :-)